# Customizing Home Page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, branding

I want my SharePoint page be customized like https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45726.html which the content be in center when I use <kbd>F12</kbd> developer tools I found that the name is `container_12`

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <h1><a href="index.html">WeatherChannel</a></h1>
            <div class="fright">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <ul class="top_menu clearfix">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign In</a>|</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Join</a>|</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="temp clearfix"><a href="#" class="cels">C°</a><a href="#" class="far">F°</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <nav class="full-width">
                <ul class="sf-menu clearfix sf-js-enabled">
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="index-1.html">Weather guides<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;»</span></a>
                        <ul style="display: none;">
                            <li><a href="#">Daily Briefing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Marine</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Climate</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Space Weather</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Fire Weather</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Aviation</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Tsunami</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Forecast Models</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Water</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">GIS</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Storm Spotters</a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">Facts and Figures</a>
                       </li></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="index-2.html">World weather news</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-3.html">Weather charts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-4.html">Footage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-5.html">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="search-block">
                <form id="search1" class="search" action="search.php" method="GET">
                    <label for="s">Enter Location</label>
                    <input id="s" type="text" name="s" value="">
                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('search1').submit()" class="button1"></a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row slider-wrapper">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="camera_wrap camera_emboss" id="camera_wrap_3" style="display: block; height: 329px; margin-bottom: 83px;"><div class="camera_fakehover"><div class="camera_src camerastarted">
                <div data-thumb="images/thumb-slide-1.jpg" data-src="images/slide-1.jpg" data-time="1500" data-trasperiod="4000" data-target="_blank">

                </div>
                <div data-thumb="images/thumb-slide-2.jpg" data-src="images/slide-2.jpg">

                </div>
                <div data-thumb="images/thumb-slide-3.jpg" data-src="images/slide-3.jpg" data-time="1500" data-trasperiod="4000" data-link="https://www.google.com/" data-target="_blank">

                </div>
                <div data-thumb="images/thumb-slide-4.jpg" data-src="images/slide-4.jpg" data-time="1500" data-trasperiod="4000" data-link="https://www.google.com/" data-target="_blank">

                <!-- </div> -->
                <div data-thumb="images/thumb-slide-5.jpg" data-src="images/slide-5.jpg" data-time="1500" data-trasperiod="4000" data-link="https://www.google.com/" data-target="_blank">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="camera_target"><div class="cameraCont"><div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_0" style="visibility: visible; display: none; z-index: 1;"><img src="images/slide-1.jpg?1495971391724" class="imgLoaded" data-alignment="" data-portrait="" width="940" height="330" style="visibility: visible; height: 330px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 940px;"><div class="camerarelative" style="width: 940px; height: 329px;"></div></div><div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_1 cameracurrent" style="display: block; z-index: 999;"><img src="images/slide-2.jpg?1495971396450" class="imgLoaded" data-alignment="" data-portrait="" width="940" height="330" style="visibility: visible; height: 330px; margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; margin-left: 0px; width: 940px;"><div class="camerarelative" style="width: 940px; height: 329px;"></div></div><div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_2 cameranext" style="display: none; z-index: 1;"><img src="images/slide-3.jpg?1495971400444" class="imgLoaded" data-alignment="" data-portrait="" width="940" height="330" style="visibility: visible; height: 330px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 940px;"><div class="camerarelative" style="width: 940px; height: 329px;"></div></div><div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_3" style="display: none; z-index: 1;"><img src="images/slide-4.jpg?1495971410700" class="imgLoaded" style="visibility: visible; height: 330px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 940px;" data-alignment="" data-portrait="" width="940" height="330"><div class="camerarelative" style="width: 940px; height: 329px;"></div></div><div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_4" style="display: none; z-index: 1;"><img src="images/slide-5.jpg?1495971413469" class="imgLoaded" style="visibility: visible; height: 330px; margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; margin-left: 0px; width: 940px;" data-alignment="" data-portrait="" width="940" height="330"><div class="camerarelative" style="width: 940px; height: 329px;"></div></div><div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_5 cameranext" style="z-index: 1; display: none;"><div class="camerarelative" style="width: 940px; height: 329px;"></div></div></div></div><div class="camera_target_content"><div class="cameraContents"><div class="cameraContent" style="display: none;"><div class="camera_caption fadeIn" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;"><div>
                    <div class="slider-text">
                        <div class="inside">Vestibulum iaculis lacinia est proin. <a href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div></div><div class="cameraContent cameracurrent" style="display: block;"><div class="camera_caption fadeIn" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;"><div>
                    <div class="slider-text">
                        <div class="inside">Reiciendis culpa a omnis. Voluptatem. <a href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div></div><div class="cameraContent" style="display: none;"><a class="camera_link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"></a><div class="camera_caption fadeIn" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;"><div>
                    <div class="slider-text">
                        <div class="inside">Laborum aliquid asperiores dicta aliquam. <a href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div></div><div class="cameraContent" style="display: none;"><a class="camera_link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"></a><div class="camera_caption fadeIn" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;"><div>
                    <div class="slider-text">
                        <div class="inside">Laudantium laboriosam adipisci. <a href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div></div><div class="cameraContent" style="display: none;"><a class="camera_link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"></a><div class="camera_caption fadeIn" style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 1;"><div>
                    <div class="slider-text">
                        <div class="inside">Perspiciatis expedita nihil repellat non. <a href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div></div></div></div><div class="camera_bar" style="display: none; top: auto; height: 7px;"><span class="camera_bar_cont" style="opacity: 0.8; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);"><span id="pie_0" style="opacity: 0.8; position: absolute; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 2px; bottom: 2px; display: block;"></span></span></div><div class="camera_prev"><span></span></div><div class="camera_next"><span></span></div></div><div><div class="camera_thumbs"><div><div class="camera_command_wrap"><div class="camera_prevThumbs hideNav"><div></div></div><div class="camera_nextThumbs"><div></div></div><div class="camera_thumbs_cont" style="visibility: visible;"><div><ul style="width: 925px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px;"><li class="pix_thumb pix_thumb_0 camera_visThumb"><span class="border-1-wrap"><img src="images/thumb-slide-1.jpg" class="camera_thumb" style="opacity: 0.7;"><span class="s-bord-1"></span><span class="s-bord-2"></span><span class="s-bord-3"></span><span class="s-bord-4"></span></span></li><li class="pix_thumb pix_thumb_1 cameracurrent camera_visThumb"><span class="border-1-wrap"><img src="images/thumb-slide-2.jpg" class="camera_thumb" style="opacity: 1;"><span class="s-bord-1"></span><span class="s-bord-2"></span><span class="s-bord-3"></span><span class="s-bord-4"></span></span></li><li class="pix_thumb pix_thumb_2 camera_visThumb"><span class="border-1-wrap"><img src="images/thumb-slide-3.jpg" class="camera_thumb" style="opacity: 0.7;"><span class="s-bord-1"></span><span class="s-bord-2"></span><span class="s-bord-3"></span><span class="s-bord-4"></span></span></li><li class="pix_thumb pix_thumb_3 camera_visThumb"><span class="border-1-wrap"><img src="images/thumb-slide-4.jpg" class="camera_thumb" style="opacity: 0.7;"><span class="s-bord-1"></span><span class="s-bord-2"></span><span class="s-bord-3"></span><span class="s-bord-4"></span></span></li><li class="pix_thumb pix_thumb_4 camera_visThumb"><span class="border-1-wrap"><img src="images/thumb-slide-5.jpg" class="camera_thumb" style="opacity: 0.7;"><span class="s-bord-1"></span><span class="s-bord-2"></span><span class="s-bord-3"></span><span class="s-bord-4"></span></span></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="camera_loader" style="display: block; visibility: visible;"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where should I put this in my SharePoint?

Comment: The link you have in question is not working. You might need to provide a screenshot.

Comment: sorry the link is https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45726.html

Answer (score 1):

You look like create a new page called `layout.aspx` and set it as `Home Page`.

Regarding your code it looks like you are using bootstrap.

**To edit this page and add your code you have 2 options:**

1. Using Browser.

   - Open your page > Edit Page.
   - Add Script Editor web Part.
   - Add your code + the reference of bootstrap js and CSS

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2. Using SharePoint Designer.

   - Open SharePoint Designer.
   - Open your site  `http://portal/sites/kms/`
   - Once the site is opened, you can edit your home page as shown below

[image]

- From the above ribbon, > click on `Advance Mode` to can edit the file.
- At the end of the page and before `</Content>` you can add your code.

An alternative way to edit your page.

- From left navigation, > Click on `Site Pages` to show all your page.
- Right click on your `layout.aspx` and select `Edit File in Advanced Mode`.

Comment: what is the class of sharepoint which I should edit and replace with my code